# Swift 3 NavigationController segue back causes wkwebview to move into wrong position

Tags: swift3, wkwebview

I have a ViewController containing a WKWebView, the view is positioned correctly the first time it loads, but after moving to another view (I'm opening another view by intercepting links from the WebView) and pressing the navigation item (back button) it briefly appears in the right place, then reloads with the top of the webview behind the navigation bar so the top of the page is cut off.

```
class HomeVC: BaseViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.top;

    super.viewDidLoad()
    addSlideMenuButton()

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let frameRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)

    let url: NSURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "services", withExtension: "html")! as NSURL

    let requestObj: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL);

    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: frameRect)
    self.webView?.load(requestObj as URLRequest)
    self.webView?.navigationDelegate = self
    self.webView?.uiDelegate = self

    self.view = self.webView
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationItem.title = ""
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationItem.title = "SELECT A SERVICE"
}


func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    let link: String = (webView.url?.absoluteString)!
    print(link)
    if(link == "file:///haircut") {
        print(link)
        self.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("WebVC")
    }
}
```

I've searched around and can't find any similar issues, nor can I see anything obvious in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have are calling `super.viewDidLoad` from `func viewDidAppear()`, what can cause unexpected behaviour. Therefore your `UIViewController` subclass will never notify its superclass, that the view has been loaded.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Do not do this before calling super!
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.top;
    // You are calling the wrong the function for super
    // It should be super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addSlideMenuButton()
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let frameRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
    let url: NSURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "services", withExtension: "html")! as NSURL
    let requestObj: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL);
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: frameRect)
    self.webView?.load(requestObj as URLRequest)
    self.webView?.navigationDelegate = self
    self.webView?.uiDelegate = self
    self.view = self.webView
}
```

Comment: Corrected those 2 mistakes, but still getting the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: I've changed the superclass call to `super.viewDidAppear(animated)` and moved the top line of code below.